# Why is `pthread_mutex_lock` needed when `pthread_mutex_trylock` is there?

Tags: pthreads, mutex

`pthread_mutex_trylock` detects deadlocks, doesn't block, then why would you even *"need"* `pthread_mutex_lock`?

Perhaps when you deliberately want the thread to block? But in that case it may result in a deadlock?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pthread_mutex_trylock` does *not* detect deadlocks.

You can use it to *avoid* deadlocks but you have to do that by wrapping your own code around it, effectively multiple calls to `pthread_mutex_trylock` in a loop with a time-out, after which your thread releases all its resources.

In any case, you can avoid deadlocks even with `pthread_mutex_lock` if you just follow the simple rule that all threads allocate resources in the same order.

You use `pthread_mutex_lock` if you just want to efficiently wait until the resource is available, without having to spin on the mutex, something which is often very inefficient. Properly designed multi-threaded applications have no need for the `pthread_mutex_trylock` variant.

Locks should only be held for the absolute minimum time to do the work and, if that's too long, you can generally redesign things so the lock time is less (such as by using the mutex to only copy data to a thread's local data areas, and having the long-running bit work on that after the mutex is released).

The pseudo-code:

```
while not pthread_mutex_trylock:
    yield
```

will continue to run your thread, waiting for the lock to be available, *especially* since there is no `pthread_yield()` in POSIX threads (though it's sometimes provided as a non-portable extension).

That means, at worst, the code segment above won't even be able to portably yield the CPU, therefore chewing up the rest of it's quantum every time through the scheduler cycle.

And at best, it will still activate the thread once per scheduler cycle just to see if the mutex can be obtained.

Whereas:

```
pthread_mutex_lock
```

will most likely *totally pause* your thread until the lock is made available, since it will move it to a waiting queue until the current lock holder releases the mutex.

That's probably the major reason why you should prefer `pthread_mutex_lock` to `pthread_mutex_trylock`.

Comment: `Properly designed multi-threaded applications have no need for the pthread_mutex_trylock variant.` Please can you elaborate a bit on this? When you talk of "properly designed", what does that mean? what is the proper way out? Any one real example?

Comment: Anisha, I mean polling a mutex is almost never necessary since, if you can't get it, you can't do what you want. People often poll so that they can do other work in the thread until the mutex is available but that sort of defeats the whole purpose of threads. If you want something else to happen while you're waiting, well, that's what _another_ thread is for. To paraphrase Yoda, "Thread. Or thread not. There is no try" :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Perhaps when you deliberately want the thread to block?

Yup, exactly in this case. But you can mimic `pthread_mutex_lock()` behavior with something like that

```
while(pthread_mutex_trylock(&mtx))
  pthread_yield()
```